# Converting Bitmap to UnmanagedImage

Tags: c#, aforge

I am writing some algorithms in AForge.Net and I need to convert Bitmap to UnmanagedImage, does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Just [RTFM](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/4a20131e-8101-d123-d72b-4f5d4b9d4e47.htm).  You get BitmapData from Bitmap.LockBits()

Answer (score 6):

There is a method for that :

[Aforge manual reference](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/ab32eca3-26c7-cd9b-90d4-b5a34115b6d7.htm) : The method creates an exact copy of specified managed image, but allocated in unmanaged memory.

```
Bitmap bitmap = ...;
UnmanagedImage unmanagedImage = UnmanagedImage.FromManagedImage(bitmap);
```

Hope this help.